# Laravel 5.3 project vendor:publish gives FileNotFoundException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

In a new laravel installation i have included several custom build packages. these packages are writing their migration files when i execute

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

however this now gives the following error

```
 [League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException]  File not found at path: 016_01_29_094442_create_xxxxx_2_f_a_tokens_table.php
```

which is not strange since the actual filename is: 2016_01_29_094442_xxxxx_2_f_a_tokens_table.php

This is what my ServiceProvider looks like:

```
class TwoFAServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    ---- SNIP -----

    public function boot() {
        ---- SNIP -----
        $this->publishMigrations();
    }

    public function publishMigrations() {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__ . '/../../migrations/' => base_path('/database/migrations'),
        ], 'migrations');
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is occuring while yesterday this worked perfectly?

--EDIT --

The problem was an update to League\Flysystem in a patch version where they made path checking more restrictive which was reverted in an update so noone should have this issue.

https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/712

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem. You should probably use backslashes in your paths, depending on your file system. See if this works:

```
public function publishMigrations() {
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__ . '\..\..\migrations\\' => base_path('database\migrations'),
    ], 'migrations');
}
```

Comment: Wow this solved it for me, thanks for the quick response!